# Como podría solucionar estos errores y me podrían ayudar con como se podría hacer la opción 3?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo este codigo en el cual tengo que hacer un menu para los maestros en el cual tenga estas 5 opciones.

1. En la primera opcion, tendria que poder el usuario registrar a los alumnos de su clase y sus calificaciones en 5 actividades.
2. En la segunda opcion, tendria que imprimir una tabla con el promedio de cada uno de los alumnos de la clase anteriormente registrados.
3. En la tercera opcion, tendria que sacar el promedio general de toda la clase y no de cada uno.
4. En la cuarta opcion, tendria que decir cual fue el alumno con mayor promedio de la clase.
5. En la quinta opcion, tendria que decir cual fue el alumno con menor promedio de la clase.

Esto es lo que llevo de código, pero me aparecen errores que no sé como solucionar. Pienso que en la opción 1 todo esta bien, pero en la 2 es donde no sabría.

Los errores empiezan en la opcion 2 y serían:

- la parte de la suma=act1+act2...,
- el segundo error que me sale seria en promedio=suma/numalumnos ese creo que sale mal debido a que la suma no esta bien hecha, pero aun asi no se si esas formulas me ayuden a saber el promedio de cada alumno o el general de todos.
- La opcion 3 es la que no sabria hacer debido a lo anterior dicho ya que en esta tendria que sacar el promedio general total.
- En la opcion 4 y 5 me aparecen errores al momento de querer usar la variable promedio (supongo que es precisamente porque no esta bien en la anterior opcion) y al intentar usar la variable nombrealumnos me marca que no existe, cuando ya la habia usado correctamente (creo) en la opcion 1.

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner miScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1) Registrar Alumnos y Calificaciones");
        System.out.println("2) Tabla de promedio final de cada alumno");
        System.out.println("3) Promedio general de la clase");
        System.out.println("4) Alumno con mayor promedio");
        System.out.println("5) Alumno con menor promedio");
        System.out.println("6) Fin del programa");

        int numalumnos = 0;
        int opcion = 0;


        do{
            System.out.println("Elija una opcion:");
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());

            if(opcion == 1){
                System.out.println("Cuantos alumnos hay en la clase?");
                numalumnos = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());

                String[] nombrealumnos = new String[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<numalumnos; i++){
                    System.out.println("Por favor deme el nombre de un alumno");  
                    nombrealumnos[i] = miScanner.nextLine();
                }

                int[] act1 = new int[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<act1.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Por favor ingrese las calificaciones de la actividad 1 en el mismo orden");
                    act1[i] = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());
                }

                int[] act2 = new int[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<act2.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Por favor ingrese las calificaciones de la actividad 2 en el mismo orden");
                    act2[i] = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());
                }

                int[] act3 = new int[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<act3.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Por favor ingrese las calificaciones de la actividad 3 en el mismo orden");
                    act3[i] = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());
                }

                int[] act4 = new int[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<act4.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Por favor ingrese las calificaciones de la actividad 4 en el mismo orden");
                    act4[i] = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());
                }

                int[] act5 = new int[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<act5.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Por favor ingrese las calificaciones de la actividad 5 en el mismo orden");
                    act5[i] = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());
                }

            }else if(opcion == 2){
                int suma = 0;

                for(int i=0; i<numalumnos; i++){
                    suma = act1[i] + act2[i] + act3[i] + act4[i] + act5[i];

                }
                double[] promedio = new double[numalumnos];
                for(int i = 0; i<promedio.length; i++){
                    promedio = (suma / numalumnos.length);
                }
            }else if(opcion == 3){

            }else if(opcion == 4){
                double mayor = promedio[0];
                String alumnomayor = nombrealumnos[0];
                for(int i = 1; i<numalumnos; i++){
                    if(promedio[i] > mayor){
                        mayor = promedio[i];
                        alumnomayor = nombrealumnos[i];
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("El alumno con mayor promedio es: " + alumnomayor);
            }else if(opcion == 5){
                double menor = promedio[0];
                String alumnomenor = nombrealumnos[0];
                for(int i = 0; i<numalumnos; i++){
                    if(promedio[i] < menor){
                        menor = promedio[i];
                        alumnomenor = nombrealumnos[i];
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("El alumno con menor promedio es: " + alumnomenor);
            }


        }while(opcion != 6);
    }

}
```

Comment: Disculpa, no es claro cuál es la pregunta. Cuáles son los errores? Cuál es la opción 3?

Comment: si, lo siento, ya actualice la pregunta. La opcion 3 aun no esta hecha ya que no estoy segura de mi procedimiento.

Comment: Hice una edición más para tratar de sugerir una forma más clara de presentar tu problema. Igual, procura siempre indicar con qué datos pruebas, qué resultó y cuál es el resultado esperado (_le pongo x, y, z datos, me da 20 y debería dar 10_). Ten en cuenta que estás presentando un código sin indicar para qué se usa y esperas que todos sepamos lo que tú ya sabes bien (cuál es el problema a resolver con este código)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el código deduzco que estás empezando a estudiar Java y no es un programa para poner en producción real. Y también deduzco que estás estudiando Arrays con este ejercicio.

El primer error que te dará será que no reconoce los arrays a la hora de hacer la suma en la opción 2. Si no te diese ese error, tendrías otro error más. A cada vuelta de bucle, la suma sería sobre-escrita por los valores de los arrays, y cuando el bucle for terminase, tendrías la suma de las notas del último alumno, y únicamente del último. Sería mejor que en vez de una variable int, fuese un array int, y a cada vuelta de bucle for rellenases una posición del array sumas.

Pero volviendo al reconocimiento de las variables:

Las variables y constantes tienen la visibilidad que les otorga el lugar donde estén declaradas. Lo más externo que una variable puede ser es de clase. Siendo visible para todos los métodos de esa clase (sin tener en cuenta el tipo de acceso). Después, un poco menos visibles son las variables que se declaran dentro de un método. Que son visibles únicamente dentro de ese método y no dentro de otros (por ejemplo, en tu ejemplo que lo haces todo dentro del método main, tus variables int numalumnos y int opcion son visibles dentro de todo el método main. Un poco menos visibles son las variables declaradas dentro de un bucle o dentro de un condicional, (y por esta razón te da errores). Las variables declaradas dentro de un bucle o dentro de un condicional son visibles única y exclusivamente dentro de ese bucle o condicional. Y cuando ese bucle o ese condicional acaba... las variables son borradas de memoria (si es que se llegaron a crear al cumplirse las condiciones de entrada).

En tu caso, creas las variables de almacenamiento de las notas en un if. Por eso, esas variables sólo son creadas si se entra en ese if. Y si no, no son creadas. Pero es más, aunque sean creadas... al acabar el if se borran de memoria.

También has de tener cuidado con el bucle do. Ya que si el bucle do termina y la condición se cumple para que vuelva a acabar, todas las variables declaradas dentro del bucle do son borradas cuando el código acaba. En la siguiente vuelta de bucle serán creadas otra vez, pero son borradas cuando el código del bucle do llega al final.

Cuando arregles eso, los demás errores podrás ir arreglándolos, como el de la opción 2 que te comento al principio, que son errores de lógica.